# adding string after regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I have files with lines like this:

```
123.45 234.56 A foo
bar boo
```

As part of a bash shell script I want to replace spaces following a
number with another string (XYZ, let's say). I can do this which
replaces all spaces (no good)

```
sed 's/ /XYZ/g' foo.txt
```

Or I can do this which replaces the right spaces but also gets rid of
the last digit (also no good)

```
perl -pe 's/\d /XYZ/g' foo.txt
```

How can I achieve the effect I'm after?

Comment: Use `\K` (a zero-width positive lookbehind assertion): `perl -pe 's/\d\K /XYZ/g' foo.txt`. See [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more information on `\K`

Comment: Try [`sed 's/\([0-9]\)  */\1XYZ/g'`](http://ideone.com/jPLqom) (2 spaces after `\)`). What is the expected result you expect for your sample text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your attempts, you need to replace a *single* space after a digit.

It is enough to use the following expression with `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\) /\1XYZ/g'
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/FFTHfD).

The `\([0-9]\)` is a **capturing group** matching a digit and storing it in a memory buffer, and a space is just *matched*. The replacement pattern contains the [**backreference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) to the value stored inside Group 1 buffer, so the digit is not lost, but restored in the result.

Note that if you need to replace all consequent spaces after a digit with `XYZ`, you may use

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)  */\1XYZ/g'
```

or

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\) \+/\1XYZ/g'
```

Comment: That seems to work perfectly.  And great explanation. The perl solution using `\K` also seems to work.

Comment: Yes, Perl `\K` will work, but if a POSIX expression is enough, I'd go for this solution.